# pyDEA running as a python script

Tags: python, data-analysis, linear-programming

I am attempting to run pyDEA. The main_gui approach does not work from wha appears to be the

ValueError: cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern

issue with the latest version of Python (I am running Python 3.8.5, Anaconda on MacOS).

Has anyone run it directly in a script? If so, do they have any sample code to show what they needed to import and call to run the DEA analysis?

Comment: It seems python > 3.5 is not supported by looking at the latest [release](https://pypi.org/project/pyDEA/) of 2017. Example: https://github.com/araith/pyDEA/issues/1

Comment: I understand this. I assumed that this was an issue of support for the stand alone gui. That was one reason I was curious about adding the computational libraries (non-gui) to other scripts.